# Set checkbox selected = !selected when click by associated image

Tags: jquery

Here is part of my html code:

```
 <div class='images'>
<img src='6.png' class='diceimg1'>
<img src='2.png' class='diceimg2'>
<img src='5.png' class='diceimg3'>
<img src='1.png' class='diceimg4'>
<img src='3.png' class='diceimg5'>
</div>
                <form method="post">                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="checkbox" value="6">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" class="checkbox" value="2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" class="checkbox" value="5">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="checkbox" value="1">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb5" class="checkbox" value="3">

    <br />                  
    <br />                                  
    </form> 
    <p class="error"></p>
```

I want this - when I click on some image with class begins with `diceimg`, jQuery function gets last symbol of its class as `$id`, gets checkbox with `name = cb+$id`, and set its selected property as `!selected`. what did I tried:

```
$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {
    $id = $this.attr("class").charAt($this.attr("class").length-1);
    $("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked") = !$("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked");
});
```

But nothing happens. Previous jQuery code works fine. Is there some errors in syntax?

Comment: What does it mean by `!selected`? Do you want to deselect it or assign the value of `!selected` to the attribute `checked` literally?

Comment: ! operator is same as in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {
    $id = $(this).attr("class").charAt($(this).attr("class").length-1);
    $("input[value='" + $id + "']").prop("checked", true)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hX8gx/1/)

With the given html, I may write is as

```
$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), index = $this.index();
    $(".checkbox").eq(index).prop("checked", true)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hX8gx/2/)

But if you want to allow only one checkbox to be selected

```
$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), index = $this.index();
    $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false).eq(index).prop("checked", true)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hX8gx/3/)

Comment: `$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {  
  $id = $(this).attr("class").charAt($(this).attr("class").length-1);
  $state = $("input[name='cb" + $id + "']").prop("checked");
  $("input[name='cb" + $id + "']").prop("checked", !$state);
 });` thats what i've wanted

Comment: You know, for a 30k+ user I would expect a better answer than this =P though, the last portion comes close to being half decent :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked",
    !$("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked"));
```

The value must be on the second parameter of `attr()` if it is used as setter.

**EDIT**

```
$("img[class^=diceimg]").click(function () {
    $id = $(this).attr("class").charAt($(this).attr("class").length-1);
    $("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked",
        !$("checkbox[name^='cb$id']").attr("checked"));
});
```

Comment: @jstq You must change `$this` to `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You should separate data from mark-up instead of working with hacks like that; for instance:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="6.png" class="diceimg" data-index="1">
  <img src="2.png" class="diceimg" data-index="2">
  <img src="5.png" class="diceimg" data-index="3">
  <img src="1.png" class="diceimg" data-index="4">
  <img src="3.png" class="diceimg" data-index="5">
</div>
```

Instead of abusing the `class` attribute to hide data, it's better to introduce a `data-x` attribute that holds the corresponding checkbox index. Doing this makes the click handler so much simpler:

```
$('.images').on('click', '.diceimg', function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index'),
    cb = document.getElementById('cb' + index);

    $('.checkbox')
      .prop('checked', false)
    cb.checked = true;
});
```

I'm using `getElementById()` because it's faster to resolve than by using `querySelectorAll()`. You would need to make this change in the form itself:

```
<form method="post">                    
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" class="checkbox" value="6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" class="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" class="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" id="cb4" class="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb5" id="cb5" class="checkbox" value="3">
</form>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/upozeb/1/)